# Connect to azure service fabric cluster with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, certificate, azure-service-fabric

I'm unable to connect to my azure service fabric cluster using powershell.

I have created a certificate "Admin" on my computer using https://support.jetglobal.com/hc/en-us/articles/235636308-How-To-Create-a-SHA-256-Self-Signed-Certificate

I have imported this certificate in my Key Vault, and added an "Admin client" authentication using "Certificate Thumbprint" authentication mode in the cluster (with the thumbprint of the created certificate)

I am using the below powershell command :

```bsh
$ClusterName= "***.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com:19000"
$ThumbPrint= "e8*****"

Connect-serviceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $ClusterName -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 `
    -X509Credential `
    -ServerCommonName "Admin" `
    -FindType FindBySubjectName `
    -FindValue "Admin" `
    -StoreLocation CurrentUser `
    -StoreName My
```

As described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster

(I have also tried with -FindByThumPrint)

I get FARBRIC_E_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: CertficateNotMatched.

What did I miss ?

Comment: It think it is exactly what I have tried in the posted code, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

**SSL certificate and SF Cluster endpoint URI must match**

There are few ways to solve this:

1. If the Cluster Certificate was issued to a custom domain (lets say `mysite.mydomain.com`) you need to use that custom domain URL into `$ClusterName`. Also both `mysite.mydomain.com` and `***.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com` must resolve to the same IP address.
2. You can also fix it by creating new certificate and pointing it to `***.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com`. After doing this, replace it with the old one in your cluster and connect by using `***.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com` endpoint.
3. This is not a fix but workaround. You can disable certificate name check by modifying `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config` and setting `checkCertificateName` to `false`. Like this ([click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/servicepointmanager-element-network-settings)):

   `<configuration><system.net><settings><servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" /></settings><system.net></configuration>`

Comment: The subject of the certificate is ***.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com, equals to the issuer. The client connection endpoint is ***.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com:19000 (so it is the same *** for the 3). Is that what you mean ? How to know where the certificate is "pointing to" ?

Comment: @Patatrack By "pointing to" I mean issuer. If it is the same it should be fine.